# Is there a way to manually find the angles of the $3:4:5$ triangle?

Tags: geometry

> Is there a way to manually find the angles of the $3:4:5$ triangle?

Been thinking of a solution all day. Can't find one that would satisfy.

Comment: The cosine rule?

Comment: without actual trigonometry, no

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually'?

Comment: The acute angles in that triangle are not nice well known multiples of $pi$. Trigonometry is all you have for finding the angles.

Comment: You can 'manually' construct the triangle ...

Comment: I suppose it could go something like "We know one angle is $\pi/2$, so now we just have to show that the other angles have a ratio of $1/2$ or $2$ between them. There might be a geometric proof there?

Comment: @QC_QAOA Your comment inspired me to post a question: [(Question 3459004)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459004/). I believe this shows that the not only is the ratio of the angles irrational but it is also transcendental.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is a decimal approximation.  One way to do this by hand is to use the Taylor series for $\arctan x$.  The first 5 terms are

$$\arctan(x) \approx x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}.$$

One angle is given by

$$\arctan(3/4) \approx 3/4-\frac{(3/4)^3}{3}+\frac{(3/4)^5}{5}-\frac{(3/4)^7}{7}+\frac{(3/4)^9}{9}$$

$$ = \frac{5928081}{9175040} = .6461095537,$$

which is not far from the actual value of $0.6435011088.$  If you want more accuracy, use more terms.

Answer (score 0):

Approximate the angle $\theta = \sin^{-1}\frac35$  via

$$\theta = \sin^{-1} t + (\sin^{-1} t)'\left(\frac35-t\right)$$

Let $t=\frac12$ and use $ \sin^{-1}\frac12 = \frac\pi6$, $(\sin^{-1} t)' = \frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ to compute $\theta$ as,

$$\theta = \frac\pi6 + \frac2{\sqrt3}\cdot\left(\frac35-\frac12\right)
=\frac\pi6+ \frac{\sqrt3}{15}$$

which is 36.6$^\circ$ vs. the exact angle 36.8$^\circ$.