# Prove that the ratio of acute angles in a $3:4:5$ triangle is irrational

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, triangles, angle, rationality-testing

Inspired by a comment by **@QC_QAOA** on [Question 3458920](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458920/is-there-a-way-to-manually-find-the-angles-of-the-345-triangle), which mentioned the ratio between the acute angles in a $3:4:5$ triangle, I would like to know if we can prove that this ratio is irrational.

The symmetries of the arguments of the functions suggested that this could be a fun and potentially tractable problem.

We can prove that the ratio is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{\tan^{-1}\frac{3}{4}}{\tan^{-1}\frac{4}{3}}=\frac{\log\left(\frac{7+24i}{25}\right)}{\log\left(\frac{-7+24i}{25}\right)}=0.69395$, with the complex-logarithm definition of $\tan^{-1}x$. So, it could also be expressed as a solution to $$25^{z}\left(7+24i\right)=25\left(-7+24i\right)^{z}$$

I had then tried to use $x^{p/q}=(x^p)^{1/q}$ but as the numbers are complex, it changed their values. The constant, nor its reciprocal, appear in the OEIS and I can't find it elsewhere.

We know that at least one of the angles (and quite likely both) is irrational, as their sum is $\frac\pi2$.

Comment: I believe that this ratio is in fact transcendental and that this follows from [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @PeterForeman Could you elaborate please? I think you might be right but I don't see how it works.

Comment: Well this theorem implies that $\log{(\alpha)}$ is transcendental for all algebraic $\alpha\ne1$ (as stated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/46503/631494) answer for example) and you have written the ratio as a single logarithm albeit with a complex base.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks, that makes sense. And it helped me find another source corroborating it: [(F. M. S. Lima - Some transcendence results](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.7289.pdf) Lemma 4) which cites back to Niven. $\frac{\ln \alpha}{\ln \beta}\notin\mathbb{A}$ whenever $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{A}/\{0\}$ and $\frac{\ln \alpha}{\ln \beta}\notin\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: (For posterity) On second thoughts regarding your prior comment, Peter, $\ln\alpha\notin\mathbb{A}$ and $\ln\beta\notin\mathbb{A}$ need not necessarily imply $\log_{\beta}\alpha\notin\mathbb{A}$ (take $\log_{2}4$ for example). We need the additional constraint that $\log_{\beta}\alpha\notin\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I didn't think I was implying this. I was just stating an implication of the theorem that seemed similar.

Comment: Nice response to that question. A definitive answer then in the negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've found a proof. Label the two angles, $a=\tan^{-1}\frac34,b=\tan^{-1}\frac43$, and their ratio, $z=\frac{a}{b}$. Then, as $a+b=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $z=\frac{\pi}{2b}-1$.

By Niven's theorem, the only values of $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ that are a rational multiple of $\pi$ and have a rational $\sin$ value are $0,\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2}$. But, as $\sin b = \frac45$, and $b$ is not equal to those values, it cannot be not a rational multiple of $\pi$. Therefore $z$ must be irrational.